# Sorting the numbers in a list / C

Tags: c

I need to sort the numbers that are entered in a list, but I am doing something wrong and it's sorting all of them except the first one.Any ideas how to fix this?

Here's my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *next;
    };
    struct node* List;

    void Add (struct node* p, int d)
   {
    struct node* q;
    q=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (q==NULL)
        printf("Not enaugh memory!");
    else
    {
        q->data=d;
        if(List==NULL)
        {
            q->next=NULL;
            List=q;
        }
        else
        {
            struct node *ptr=List;
            while((ptr->next!=NULL)&&(ptr->next->data>d))
            {
                ptr=ptr->next;
            }
            q->next=ptr->next;
            ptr->next=q;

        }
    }
}


    int main()
    {
        int n,i,a;
        printf("How much numbers are you going to enter? ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            printf("\nEnter a number: ");
            scanf("%d",&a);
            Add(List,a);
        }
        printf("\nThe sorted numbers are: ");
        struct node *ptr=List;
        while(ptr!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%d\t",ptr->data);
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        printf("\n\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
```

Thanks for the help in advance :-)

Comment: What this does" `while((ptr!=NULL)&&(ptr->next->data>d))` when there is **one** element in the list?

Answer (score 0):

in add() function,

```
if(List==p)
```

this statement is true for all elements you insert to list since the call to add is,

```
Add(List,a);
```

so `p=List`. therefore the sorting code written in `else` part is not executed.
Also add statements to check for empty initial list.
You can use code similar to this,

```
void Add (int d)
{
    struct node* q;
    q=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (q==NULL)
        printf("Not enaugh memory!");
    else
    {
        q->data=d;
        if(List==NULL)
        {
            q->next=NULL;
            List=q;
        }
        else
        {
            struct node *ptr=List;
            while((ptr->next!=NULL)&&(ptr->next->data>d))
            {
                ptr=ptr->next;
            }
            q->next=ptr->next;
            ptr->next=q;

        }
    }
}
```

Since list is a global variable you dont need to pass it to `Add()` function. change the function call to

```
 Add(a);
```

Comment: Ok so what should I change? I am not really good at programming (as you can tell) :/

Comment: @Monster ok. i added code. you can try code similar to it

Comment: Thank you so much! I edited the main post so you can see the code as I changed it. Now it's sorting everything EXCEPT the first number I enter. Any other advices?

Answer (score 0):

You always call `Add` with `List` as the first parameter, so it's alway true inside `Add` that `(List==p)`. Consequently each new item is just inserted at the front of the list and there is no sorting at all.

**EDIT 1**

A good practice would be sending a list to the `Add` routine as a parameter. Or, if you want to keep it external, just don't give it to `Add` at all and test `if(List == NULL)`

```
void Add( int d)
{
    // ... alloc 'q' and fill q->d here, then:
    if(List == NULL)
    {
        q->next = NULL;
        List = q;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node *b;  // put q after b
        for( b = List; b->next != NULL; b = b->next)
            if( b->next->data >= d)
                break;
        q->next = b->next;
        b->next = q;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Example of transferring the list to a function by parameter

```
void Add( struct node **n, int d)
{
    // ... alloc 'q' and fill q->d here, then:

    while( *n != NULL && (*n)->data < d)
        n = & (*n)->next;

    q->next = *n;
    *n = q;
}

int main()
{
    // ...
    Add( &List, a);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok so what should I change? I am not really good at programming (as you can tell) :/

Answer (score 0):

```
void Add (struct node* p, int d){
    struct node* q;
    q=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (q==NULL)
        printf("Not enaugh memory!");
    else{
        q->data=d;
        if(List==NULL || List->data < d){//modify this line
            q->next= List;//and change NULL to List
            List=q;
        } else {
            struct node *ptr=List;
            while((ptr->next!=NULL)&&(ptr->next->data>d)){
                ptr=ptr->next;
            }
            q->next=ptr->next;
            ptr->next=q;
        }
    }
}
```